# SRT : No Room to Store Incoming Packets when we stream SRT streams through VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, srt, hikvision

Hope all you are doing well.

Actually i was trying to stream a media file using VLC by SRT protocol. For which, srt-live-transmit is used as converter in between SRT Listener and VLC UDP streams. srt-live-transmit used to convert udp to srt streams(mpegts). But when i tried to do that, after few seconds, i got error in srt-live-transmit terminal that :
***No room to store incoming packet:***

What should be the reason for this error? And if anyone know anything about this problem, please share info. It would be helpful.
Thank you.